# Full text search through API

Tags: search

A client of my asked me to implement a Search functionality on their website, which interfaces with CiviCRM through the API. The 'Full text search' functionality of CiviCRM does exactly what is required, so I was wondering, is it possible to call it through the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE!  I don't think you can call full-text search through the API currently. But you could write an extension to provide that as an API call based on CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/FullText.php

However, that is a heavy search and can cause problems on a large site. You might be better to refine what you really need to search for and then use APIv4 to do the searches.

Comment: Thanks Aidan. I'll see what we can do then :-)